# Removing horizontal scrollbar from embedded gist

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages, gist

I have a Github gist embedded on my site. So far so good. Unfortunately, it displays a horizontal scrollbar that I just can't seem to get rid of. Code is this:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <style type="text/css">

            .gist, .gist-file, .gist-meta {
                font: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, freesans, clean, sans-serif;
                background-color:#ffffff !important;
                border: none !important; 
                border-radius: 0;
                border-bottom: none;
                overflow-x: hidden !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                overflow: hidden !important;
                width: 100%;
                align-self: center;
             } 
        
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <script class="test" src=.js"></script> 

    </body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the script tag, I've tried a lot of different things to remove it. The CSS works, meaning that I can use those classes to manipulate the gist somewhat, but I just can't seem to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar. Please help. What can I do here? Using Chrome. site is on Github Pages.

EDIT: Even when I create an entirely new project for  just this html file I get the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I don't see horizontal scrollbars with the given code.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why that is.. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the gist code it seems that it embeds the result in an `iframe` (with class "render-viewer"). The fact that it is embedded in an iframe will cause issues with getting CSS to work, but you can try adding `.render-viewer` (or just `iframe`) to your CSS class names and look up different ways to style an iframe from a parent document

Comment: Yes it embeds in an iframe. Adding .render-viewer and .iframe unfortunately doesn't  do anything. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: there is a typo: `<script class="test" src=.js"></script>`

Comment: @jsv Yes. Removed that part  as it had the URL for my website and showed up when googling it.